# Regression Time Series

Tags: rstudio

I have 6 months data from November 2015 to April 2016 (around 3600 rows each). I have to predict the data for the month May. I think it is a non stationary time series. I am new to R programming. Please help.

The data Looks like this.

```
Nov dec Jan Feb Mar Apr   May
0   0   0   2   0   0      ?
1   1   0   0   0   1      ?
0   1   0   0   1   0      ?
5   2   1   0   1   3      ?
0   0   2   0   1   0      ?
4   0   2   0   1   1      ?
```

Comment: What do you have so far? What have you tried? Did you read relevant literature?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to predict the values of May month and when I use ar model it gives a constant answer which is not of any help. I have tried various models with respect to time series by testing with p,d,q values of arima. I get a constant Output. I have tried HoltWinters, ets model and simple exponential smoothing.None seems to work. Please suggest

Comment: Please only use the `rstudio` tag if your question concerns the RStudio code editor. You wouldn't use a `pen-and-paper` tag when asking a question about grammar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your question is. How to make predictions? Or how to test for (non-)stationary time series?

To test for a stationary time series, install the `tseries` package. Do this by typing `install.packages("tseries")` in the console and adding the following command to your code `library(tseries)` (this command loads the installed package). Then you can use the `adf.test` function to perform an Augmented Dickey-Fuller test. For more information on how to use this function type `?adf.test` after you installed and loaded the `tseries` package.

How to make forecasts is totally depends on the model you use. If you, for example, make an AR model using the `ar` function, you can make predictions using the `predict.ar` function. It is usually sufficient to just use `predict` since R recognizes the object (an `ar` object in my example) and therefore knows to call `predict.ar`.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:
Here is a simple piece of code to show you how I would make predictions for your dataset

```
    #This is not an efficient code, but intstructive and easy readable imo
    #I will make an AR(p) model, where p is chosen by the ar() function
    #note that for an AR model, we need a time series
    #I make an AR model for each row, since each row reperesents the time series of 1 subject in your data

    #load data
    myData <- read.csv(FILENAME)

    May <- NULL #use this to store the predictions for May
    for (i in 1:nrow(myData))
    {
      timeSeries <- t(myData[i,]) #for an ar model, we need a time series, so the rows in myData
      arModel <- ar(timeSeries) #build the model
      arPrediction <- predict(arModel) #make the prediction
      May <- rbind(May, arPrediction) #add the prediction to other predictions
    }

data <- round(runif(10, min = 0, max = 10))
arModel <- ar(data)
arPrediction <- predict(arModel)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to predict the values of May month and when I use ar model it gives a constant answer which is not of any help. Please suggest.

Comment: If you edit your answer with a reproducible code, it will be way easier to help you and make suggestions :)

Comment: The code is as follows:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            >ar = arima(y_time$values,order = c(2,1,2)) #y_time is variable stacked from all months from November to April eg:0,1,0,5,0,4,0,1,1,2,0,0.....to make a univariate time series data
> fc.arima = forecast(ar,h=200) #next 200 predictions
> fc.arima

Comment: Still not reproducible.. Also, it would be easier to edit your question with the code instead of giving the code in the comments (which is almost unreadable). But what I notice is that you make 200 step ahead predictions which corresponds to predictions for 16-17 years in the future. You said you wanted to predict only for May, so you should set h = 1.

Comment: ok, but can you give me an idea of how to code for building the time series model for this dataset using arima or any other time series model for this example?

Comment: If you give me a reproducible code for make a data frame, I can write some code for a basic model + predictions which you can tweak to suit your needs

Comment: I have shared the dataset with a link mydataset.csv here . I think you can Import and then build the model. [mydataset.csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UswuoCnBe1b3_ZYdwqT7I_UtyKFLiAhCYnmSeqpE_IA/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and replies. I will try tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: hallo! I tried running the code but i'am getting a strange errror:   "Error in ar.yw.default(x, aic = aic, order.max = order.max, na.action = na.action,  : 
  'order.max' must be >= 1 "

Comment: Thank you! The Problem is i'am getting the same single value for May but I should be getting similar to how values are there for past months.

Comment: The Problem is whenever i introduce a Loop same error Comes. I'am not able to enter the required data. Any idea of how to enter my data? The random number code worked with the last 3 lines but I'am not able to give my data. Sorry I'am a beginner. I'am bugging you a lot

Comment: for(i in 1:nrow(new_dataframe_train)){
+ data<-new_dataframe_train[i,]
+ data<-as.numeric(data)
+ arModel <- ar(data)
+ arPrediction <- predict(arModel)
+ May <- rbind(May, arPrediction) 
+ }

Comment: Thank you so much but the values dont read completely. Only till 391 values read. Any idea?

Comment: new_dataframe_train<-read.csv("C:/Users/h01subra/Desktop/Neuer Ordner/month_dataset.csv",sep=";")
> May<-NULL
> for(i in 1:nrow(new_dataframe_train)){
+    data<-new_dataframe_train[i,]
+    data<-as.numeric(data)
+    data<-t(new_dataframe_train[i,])
+  arModel <- ar(data)
+    arPrediction <- predict(arModel)
+    May <- rbind(May, arPrediction$pred)
+    } . This I tried and I'am getting "Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : Missing Values in Object error"

Comment: Again just 391 rows are reading with an error : "Series with Variance NULL"

Comment: Nope. I removed all the NA values but still getting the same error. My code is like this now:   > new_dataframe_train<-read.csv("C:/Users/h01subra/Desktop/Neuer Ordner/month_dataset.csv",sep=";")
> newdata <- na.omit(new_dataframe_train)
> May<-NULL
> for(i in 1:nrow(newdata)){
+    data<-newdata[i,]
+    data<-as.numeric(data)
+    data<-t(newdata[i,])
+  arModel <- ar(data)
+    arPrediction <- predict(arModel)
+    May <- rbind(May, arPrediction$pred)
+    }

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I corrected the error and everything is working fine.